# Check if a path in remote server is a directory JSch

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

How would i check if a path in a SFTP remote server is a directory or file, i could check if the path ends with an extension e.g

- something/something.txt false because it has an extension which means it's not a directory
- something/something true because it doesn't have an extension which means it's a directory

but technically there are files that has no extension and the program will think it's a directory, and this method isn't really the best, is there another way to check if a path is a directory. I'm using the `JSch` library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the good old `java.io.File#isDirectory()`? Or `java.nio.file.Files.isDirectory()`?

Most probably you could get a `File` or `Path` from a `URL`. There are constructors which specify the protocol and host, like `URL​(String protocol, String host, int port, String file)`

---

Now that you told me about ChannelSftp (I don't know JSch). I have found a method which will help:
[stat()](https://www.docjava.com/book/cgij/jdoc/net/ssh/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#stat(java.lang.String)) and you can call `sftpATTRS.isDir()`:

`channel.stat(filePath).isDir()`

Comment: That's what i thought, but ChannelSftp doesn't have a isDirectory method (or something similar) and i don't know how to get a File instance of the path in the remote server
Edit: hmm maybe that would be possible to do

Comment: Ok i will do some reading about stat() and try using it, thanks for the help